# How to change Audio inputs properly?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to change audio inputs From delphi application

i am doing something like this

```
const
  DRVM_MAPPER = $2000;
  DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_GET = DRVM_MAPPER+21;
  DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET = DRVM_MAPPER+22;


function ChangePrimarySndInDevice(dev: cardinal): integer;
begin
  result := waveInMessage(HWAVEIN(WAVE_MAPPER), DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET, dev, 0);
end;


var
 Adev : Integer;
begin
//
Adev := combobox1.ItemIndex;
if ChangePrimarySndInDevice(Adev) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR then
begin
showmessage('ok');

end;
```

but the device did not set i am using windows 8

this is how i grab devices names

```
procedure TMainForm.GetInDevices;
var
  dev: Integer;
  caps: TWaveInCaps;
begin
  ComboBox1.Clear;
  for dev := 0 to waveInGetNumDevs - 1 do
  begin
    waveInGetDevCaps(dev, @caps, sizeof(TWaveInCaps));
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(caps.szPname);
  end;
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
end;
```

Comment: What's the actual return value of `ChangePrimarySndInDevice(Adev)` call?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann `8`

Comment: This is the value of `MMSYSERR_NOTSUPPORTED` constant, right? Looks like the driver in place does not support this function.

Comment: maybe the drivers list is not written correctly ? because i cannot see the full name of tthe driver i see a part of it in the `combobox1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I needed to do this too, but I did not manage to do it directly from within Delphi. I used nircmd to set the default input/output

I used the same method to get the names, but stripped of the beginning if there are parentheses in the name.

```
 function TrimParenthesis(devname:string):string;
 var
   parpos:integer;
 begin
   parpos:=pos('(',devname);
   if parpos>0 then
     result:=Trim(LeftStr(devname,parpos-1))
   else
     result:=devname;
 end;
```

Then execute nircmd through windows.createprocess(). the nircmdc.exe should be in the application directory. It is called 3 times to account for all possible roles.

```
procedure SetSoundDevice(devname:string);
var
  proc_id:DWORD;
begin  
  execute_program(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'nircmdc.exe','setdefaultsounddevice "'+devname+'" 0',proc_id,true);
  execute_program(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'nircmdc.exe','setdefaultsounddevice "'+devname+'" 1',proc_id,true);
  execute_program(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'nircmdc.exe','setdefaultsounddevice "'+devname+'" 2',proc_id,true);
end;
```